# I can not enter admin login page,,when i try to enter admin/lodin page there show Class "NumberFormatter" not found

Tags: php, laravel

I was trying to build bagisto E-Commerce framework which is  built by Laravel and PHP. I have follow a tutorial. i can enter defult page which address are http://127.0.0.1:8000 . But after that i can not enter http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login then a error shows that Class "NumberFormatter" not found.
This is the default page where i can enter:

[image: default page]

And this is the error occur when i am trying to access http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login

[image: error]

I am trying to resolve but failed again and again

Comment: did you run composer install and composer dump-autoload

Comment: no i had try this also

Comment: You could use a custom function form formatting instead. I once had this issue. Tried so many fixed without success until I had to write my own Number formatting function.

Comment: But where i use custom function??? and how?